# Z390 motherboard that supports two 4K monitors

Tags: motherboard

I'm trying to find a Z390 motherboard with built-in support for two 4K DisplayPort monitors.

I can see that many have USB-C but I can't find any info if any of them support DisplayPort over that connector.

Some of the motherboards have a DisplayPort connector, but I can-t find any info on which version of DisplayPort they have.

I've realized that 100% of the Z390 are for gamers, and that gamers use a dedicated GPU with ports of its own, but in this setup no extra GPU besides the Intel HD 630 is required or needed.

Can you help me find a motherboard with support for two 4K monitors using DisplayPort?

Comment: "no extra GPU... is needed" Are you sure about that? Driving two large 4K monitors _is_ a decent graphics load - you may not need a top-end card, but I'm not sure you'll get away with just the integrated stuff.

Comment: I've two 4K monitors @ 60 Hz and I use an Intel HD 630 without any lags at all.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder "without any lags at all" <- depends on the additional load from other applications (e.g. games). Try watching a [4K HFR video on each monitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXb3EKWsInQ) and things might not be so smooth. I would **highly** recommend ArtOfCode's recommendation for an additional graphics card if you can afford it.

Comment: The question is *not* about a graphics card. It's about a motherboard with dual DisplayPort. There will never be games played on it and YouTube will never ever be accessed on it.

Comment: Watching that 4K video works fine on my dual 4K setup with Intel HD 630.

Answer (score 1):

The Supero Core Gaming C9Z390 range of boards (in ATX form factor) offers two Display Port 1.2 outputs. So each can drive a 4K display.

Supero is a Supermicro brand.

Alternatively, a few boards offer a HDMI 2.0 port plus a DP port.